# ASP.NET MVC 3 - @Html.DropDownList - How do I change the description?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The following code in a cshtml file creates a dropdown with a list of Contacts, but the field it uses for the description of values, is not the one I want to display.

How do I force it to choose data from a different field in the Contact object?

```
    @Html.DropDownList("ContactId", String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.OtherContactId, 
    new SelectList(Model.ContactList, "ContactId", "ContactValue", 
        Model.OtherContactId), "-- Select --")
```

where, `Model.ContactList` is populated in your controller action.

p.s. I'm not entirely certain whether you mean change the title of the select option text or the property that is updated, so have presented a kind of hybrid offering

Comment: Thanks, I needed to set it in the controller. 

ViewBag.ContactId = new SelectList(db.Contacts, "ContactId", "FullNameAndCompany");

Comment: glad it helped you, it can be a little tricky navigating the various api syntaxes at times :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this on the server side(controller):

```
ViewBag.ContactList = new SelectList(iContactRepository.GetAllContacts(),
                                     "ContactId", "Name", contactDefault.ContactId);

//Here the method GetAllContacts returns Iqueryable<Contact>.
```

And this on the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ContactIdSelect", ViewBag.ContactList as SelectList)
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx) is the SelectList documentation.

Hope it helps.